# Test ASP.NET site locally with SSL on IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-5

I need to test an ASP.NET site that requires SSL locally. I think IIS7 with the self-signing certs would do the trick, however, I am on XP.

Any idea how I could test the site locally over https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS Resource Kit will help you with this in XP. use the SelfSSL utility to create a self signed cert. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelfSSL or OpenSSL to create a self-signed certificate. Here are instructions on how to do this.

http://www.somacon.com/p41.php

http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html